# How can you modify a DBIx::Class::Row in place?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

Using DBIx::Class::ResultSet is it possible to make changes to the results in memory as attempted below?

```
my @results = $self->search(...);

for my $result (@results) {
  my $row = {$result->get_columns};
  $row->{fieldname} = 'something else';
}

return @results;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A column accessor is generated by DBIx::Class for every column you define.
It can be used both as a reader

```
my $value = $row->columnname;
```

and as a writer

```
$row->columnname('new value');
```

Comment: What if `fieldname` is not column name?

Comment: When defining the columns you can specify an accessor name that's different from the column name but I don't recommend it because it makes things harder because for example in search you can only use the column name, not the accessor names. That will confuse people reading the code later.

Comment: What if `fieldname` is not a column name, nor an accessor name?

Comment: Then you should use the get_column method.

Answer (score -3):

You may use something like this:

```
my @rows = $self->search(
    {...},
    {result_class => 'DBIx::Class::ResultClass::HashRefInflator'}
);

for my $row (@rows) {
    $row->{fieldname} = 'something else';
}

return @rows;
```

Comment: Please don't mangle the internal variables of the DBIx::Class::Row object! Note that this is a general advice not specific to DBIx::Class, Perl or any other language that allows you to do this.

Comment: @abraxxa Using of `DBIx::Class::ResultClass::HashRefInflator` in `search` returns hash refs, not objects.

Comment: Using it means you don't get a row object back and thus can't update the database using it.

Comment: @abraxxa This condition is not in the question.